# The regular expression says no match found it is just a simple expression

Tags: android

The output it says no match found I dont know why. It should return "hellio" but not. Is there any mistake I have made?

```
try{ 
    String ss="hellio helli hrl";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hellio");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
    matcher.matches();
    Log.v("dd",matcher.toMatchResult().group());   
} catch(Exception e){
    Log.v("h",e.toString());  
}
```

I have tried this also:

```
try{ 
    String ss="hellio helli hrl";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hellio");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
    Log.v("dd",matcher.toMatchResult().group()); 
} catch(Exception e){
    Log.v("h",e.toString());  
}
```

I have tried this also:

```
try{ 
    String ss="hellio helli hrl";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hellio");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
    Log.v("dd",matcher.group()); 
} catch(Exception e){
    Log.v("h",e.toString());  
}
```

Comment: add `matcher.find();`

Answer (score 0):

You were not calling `find()` try this

```
String ss="hellio helli hrl";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hellio");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

output

```
hellio
```

Comment: @VeeraPrasad if it answer you question you can accept it as the answer